# python pyrobot module giving error

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I installed the pyrobot module through pip, but is still getting this error. This is in anaconda.

How do I solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed this problem as well.

When you have a look inside your `site-packages/pyrobot` you will notice the `forms` folder is missing, however, when you have a look at the original github repo you can see this folder.

You can try manually copying the `forms` folder into `site-packages/pyrobot`. Please be aware when you manually copy the folder, `pip uninstall pyrobot` will not delete what you copied. So you have to manually delete as well.

Im not sure. Should not it be `from pyrobot import RoboBrowser` instead of `from pyrobot import Robot`?

**Answer updated:**

lol, It is confusing because
`https://github.com/jmcarp/pyrobot` and `https://github.com/chriskiehl/pyrobot` have same name but are different library.

`pip install pyrobot` installs `https://github.com/jmcarp/pyrobot` but if Im not mistaken what you want is this `https://github.com/chriskiehl/pyrobot`.

If so, you can just directly copy one file `pyrobot.py` from `https://github.com/chriskiehl/pyrobot` into your project source directory and use it.

Unfortunately I can not test it because it is a windows only library.

Comment: I was actually trying to do some cool stuffs mentioned [link](https://github.com/chriskiehl/pyrobot), but  `from pyrobot import Robot` is not working. Can you please suggest something else?